# Why do cat and more wrap lines differently?

Tags: linux, cat, more

It seems that `more` adds line breaks, whereas `cat` does not. As a result `cat` results will change to fit the terminal window if I resize the window, whereas `more` results stay put with the line breaks added the first time. My question is why, and is there any way to make `more` behave like `cat`? (I really don't like this setting of more, when I copy I end up getting the line breaks that I don't want.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [`man more`](https://manpages.debian.org/util-linux/more.1):

> **-f** Count logical lines, rather than screen lines (i.e., **long lines are not folded**).

preceded by:

> OPTIONS
>   Options are also taken from the **environment variable MORE**
>   (make sure to precede them with a dash (-)) but command-line options
>   will override those.

So at your convenience you can either do:

```
more -f /some/file/with/long/lines
```

or export it in the `MORE` variable:

```
$ export MORE=-f
$ more /some/file/with/long/lines
```

This should probably be put in some shell login script such as `$HOME/.profile`.

Comment: I saw you asked "why" and admit I'm still dumbfounded at what historical reason probably related to vt100 behaviour or email conventions or even very old printer output (3 random wild guesses)  made want having `more` doing this.

Comment: ah, I didn't realize 'fold' means something different from 'wrap' here. Thanks so much!!